# Blank entry in ggplot legend (geom_point)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to make a simple scatterplot in ggplot, but I've never encountered this before: a legend entry with a colored dot but no label and no presence in the plot itself. What gives?

**Data & Visualization**
Here's the data for reproduction:

```
year,rate,study
1987,0.014,"A"
1987,0.0184,"B"
1987,0.0283,"B"
1987,0.0186,"B"
1988,,
1989,,
1990,,
1991,0.0368,"B"
1991,0.0317,"B"
1991,0.0271,"B"
1992,,
1993,,
1994,,
1995,,
1996,0.039,"A"
1996,0.0616,"B"
1996,0.0626,"B"
1996,0.0591,"B"
1997,0.055,"C"
1998,,
1999,,
2000,,
2001,,
2002,0.0674,"D"
2003,,
2004,0.07,"C"
2004,0.0855,"E"
2005,,
2006,,
2007,,
2008,,
2009,,
2010,,
2011,0.089,"C"
2012,,
2013,,
2014,0.09,"E"
2015,,
2016,,
```

Here's the code for the plot (dataset imported from csv as `d`):

```
d_plot <- ggplot(data = d, aes(year, rate)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=year, y=rate, color = study))
```

And finally, here's the wonky graphic (note the dot above A):

[image: Note the dot above A]

**Hypothesis and Attempts to Solve**

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that a lot of years have no "rate" nor any "study", so I've gone through similar posts and tried using `na.omit` and `filter()` here and there, but nothing's worked so far.

Any takers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that it has to do with the fact that years have no `rate`. If you remove the rows where `rate` is `NA`, you don't get the extra dot.

```
ggplot(data = d[!is.na(d$rate), ], aes(year, rate)) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x=year, y=rate, color = study))
```

[image: picture without a dot]

Comment: Didn't even read your code before I commented. Thanks, C. Braun!